# Multiple Carts for the same customer

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, b2b

I am working on a B2B website in which the customers have sub accounts. I have added a attribute in the quote and order for including the sub user ID. When the different sub user login I am able to set the privileges and dashboard links. But I am not able to load separate cart for each sub user. Is there any possible way in magento.

I have tried many options but nothing is giving the output

```
                $currentusertype='customer';
                $customerid='';
                if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getUserType()){
                    $currentusertype=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getUserType();
                }
                $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
                $quotes = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();
                $quotes->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer->getId());
                if($currentusertype=='customer'){
                    $quotes->addFieldToFilter('customerid',$customer->getId());
                    $quotes->addFieldToFilter('customertype',$currentusertype);
                    $customerid=$customer->getId();
                } else {

                    $quotes->addFieldToFilter('customerid',Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getUserId());
                    $quotes->addFieldToFilter('customertype',$currentusertype);
                    $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getUserId();

                }
                if($quotes->count()){
                    Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->setQuoteId($quotes->getFirstItem()->getId());
                    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

                }else{
                    $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customer);
                    $quoteObj->setCustomerid($customerid)->setCustomertype($currentusertype)->save();
                    Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->setQuoteId($quoteObj->getId());
                    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found an idea.

I have overridden the Class `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote`

And edited the function `loadByCustomerId($quote, $customerId)`.

I have loaded the quote that i have assigned the `customertype` and `customerid`.

and assigned that data.

```
$quotes = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();
$quotes->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer->getId());$quotes->addFieldToFilter('customerid',Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getUserId());
$quotes->addFieldToFilter('customertype',$currentusertype);
$customerid=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getUserId();
$quote->setData($quotes->getFirstItem()->getData());
```